# Gcm notification received after hours on some devices

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use gcm notification. My server code is working fine and I am getting success as acknowledgment.

The problem is notification is getting sent properly :

1) In most of devices notification is received instantaneously.
   Tested on google nexus,sony phones.

2) Other devices are also receiving notification but after several hours. Yes, **hours**. Tested on Karbonn, Micromax some phones.

*Note:*

All the devices are connected to the same wifi so network connectivity not an issue . Using php at server side;
There are several unanswered questions regarding this topic . I am hereby listing some of them:

[gcm notification is not working on some devices like micromax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619831/gcm-notification-is-not-working-on-some-devices-like-micromax)

[One device doesn't receive push notifications (GCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132407/one-device-doesnt-receive-push-notifications-gcm)

[Push notifications delay with GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741114/push-notifications-delay-with-gcm)

Anyone else having similar problem attach your question too.

*Failed trials of rectification:*

I have also made changes to code after going through several questions in which the developers found their solution like 
removing this line of code from `onHandleIntent()`

```
GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```

Or changing `delay_while_ideal` value to `true/false` in server code.

Or separately mentioning receiver and registration intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<category android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient" />
</intent-filter>
```

*Code:
Android.manifest*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nothing.gcmclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.nothing.gcmclient" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService"></service>

        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterChatButtonActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register_chat_button" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatHistory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MessageScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message_screen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*Code: GCMNotificationIntentService.java*

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                String sender=extras.get(Config.SENDER).toString().toLowerCase();
                String message=extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY).toString();

                if(!RegisterActivity.appVisible==true)
                {
                    sendNotification("New message Received from "+ extras.get(Config.SENDER));
                }
            }
        }
        //GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ChatHistory.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
                .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

Experts please look into the problem and suggest the appropriate cause and solution. My app would be of no use if it works only for certain phones.If you need any more file in our application kindly inform.

PS- Kindly read the entire question and then post your comments or answers or mark duplicate if necessary.

Comment: Sounds like either a device problem or a GCM server problem, (probably device). Neither of which you will be able to fix

Comment: Tried it on 7 devices. Failed for three. That percentage is high enough to believe device specific problem

Comment: You can try two official demo app [here](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android) and [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm). If the problem still exist, I think it surely a device specific problem, so maybe you can find some support company by company.

Comment: You must handle gcm registration id properly, actually some times it be very abrupt situation for gcm to identify gcm registration id. Your whole code is good you just handle gcm id properly and update every time.

Comment: Do you receive notifications from other apps instantly on these devices or are these also delayed? Maybe you have general connectivity issues with GCM on these devices. Dial *#*#426#*#* and check if the device is connected to Google Play Services. Usually port 5228 is used, but maybe it is blocked in your network. In this case port 443 is used as fallback, but some devices seem to don't use the fallback and therefore fail to receive push notifications. Have a look at this thread on google forum for more information...

Comment: USSD code running then invalid getting displayed for that number

Comment: Actually this is how GCM works, as I recall it was stated that it might take up to 12 hours for notification to reach the device (or it may even not reach it at all). If you need faster (and reliable) connection channel then I would recommend you to have a  look at websockets

Comment: @user2653926 Sorry, the correct USSD code is `*#*#426#*#*` and the here is the link to the corresponding post on google forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/fslYqYrULto/lU2D3Qe1mugJ

Comment: It displays not connected.Now what I need to do ??

Comment: Connect also getting failed

Comment: @user2653926 See my new answer...

Answer (score 8):

- GCM works through Google Play Services
- Devices connect to Google Play Services through **TCP on port 5228**
- Devices should use port 443 as fallback if port 5228 is blocked, but apparently they just don't use the fallback sometimes (happened to multiple of my devices)
- Device sends a **heartbeat packet to Google Play Services** every 28 minutes on mobile and 15 minutes on wifi
- You can check the connection state, heartbeat interval, connection address and port, etc. dialing `*#*#426#*#*` on a device

**How to fix common issues when devices don't connect to Google Play Services on wifi or lose connection frequently**:

1. **Open port 5228**
2. **Configure your routers, so they don't kill inactive tcp connections before waiting at least 15 minutes**

See [this post on Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/connecting-to-networks-and-devices/fslYqYrULto) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. That code was specially helpful.

Comment: Can you please explain how to 'open port 5228'?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

First, make sure your messages dont exceed the maximum char length.
Second, a lot of people told me it could be firewall issues from the phones or network, but other apps (like whatsapp) worked smoothly.
After a couple weeks, It stopped the delays and my problems solved alone.

I know this is not a real solution, but try waiting, develop other things and come back to test it again in a couple weeks.

Comment: No, in my case, I axually gave up to support all devices and went on building the app. When the app was finished, I just re-tested and all was working.. my advice is to not stop at this, finish your app as if it was working properly, than re-test. Probably Google system has some app reliability or some kind of scalable grading system

Answer (score 1):

Since you receive notifications on some devices as expected I assume your manifest and Java code which you posted basically should be OK. Could you post your `GcmBroadcastReceiver`-class? It should be something like this:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

/**
 * Starts GcmIntentService which handles the intent.
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

This class is responsible for waking up your app (if your app´s process is not running yet) and calling your service, if you do not implement it like this the Android system will not start your GCMNotificationIntentService because the app is not running yet hence no notification can be displayed. This also would explain why the notifications are received on some devices immediately. So I assume you receive the notification on each device, but just not display it instantly.

Furthermore it is definitly not necessary to call `GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);` in the GCMNotificationIntentService if your BroadcastReceiver is correct because this line even cannot have any effect since it is never called (if my assumption is right, that your BroadcastReceiver is the problem).

As far as I see you are using the old version of the GCM-API. I don´t know if you know the newer GCM-API being available since a few weeks. I also had a similar issue with the old version some time ago but since I am using the new API (inlcuding InstanceID-API which replaces the old Registration ID) I was never having any notification-delay-issue anymore.

I can strongly recommmend to implement the new GCM-API. See the [docs for further information](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). And [that´s the doc](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation) for the InstanceID-API.

Comment: Would go through that . Thanks